# Barnes-Hut N-body simulator

Tags: c++, beginner, simulation, physics, sfml

I have written an n-body simulator, implementing the Barnes-Hut algorithm. Please comment on anything you can see wrong with this.

[Wikipedia Barnes-Hut page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation)

[image: Image of galaxy]

This is a screen shot of the simulation 20 hours in. All the particles spawn in a uniform disk, given an initial velocity in order to "orbit" the "Galactic center" (an invisible object at the center of the simulation, and therefore a galaxy, with `GalaticCenterMass` mass). They then swirl around and around like a galaxy does and because the particles attract each other they form wonderful pictures and time lapse animations.

**Node.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

struct Body
{
    float posX, posY;           //position x and y
    float velX, velY;           //velocity x and y
    double forceX, forceY;      //force acting on object since last frame
    float mass;                 //mass of object
};

class Node
{
public:
    std::vector<Body*> Bodies;
    std::vector<Node*> Child;
    bool HasChildren;

    float posX, posY;
    float width, height;
    float TotalMass;
    float CenterOfMassx;
    float CenterOfMassy;
    unsigned int Depth;
    bool IsUsed;            //For testing, delete this later

    Node();
    Node(unsigned int pdepth);
    ~Node();
    void GenerateChildren();
    void SetParam(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float pwidth, float pheight, float px = 0, float py = 0);
    void Reset();
};
```

**Node.cpp:**

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <memory>

#define _MAX_DEPTH 100

Node::Node(unsigned int pDepth)
{
    HasChildren = false;
    Depth = pDepth;
}

Node::Node()
{
    HasChildren = false;
    Depth = 0;
}

void Node::GenerateChildren()
{
    std::vector<Body*> q1Bodies, q2Bodies, q3Bodies, q4Bodies;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Bodies.size(); i++)
    {
        if (Bodies[i]->posX < (posX + (width / 2)))     //if true, 1st or 3rd
        {
            if (Bodies[i]->posY < (posY + (height / 2)))    //1
            {
                q1Bodies.push_back(Bodies[i]);
            }
            else //3
            {
                q3Bodies.push_back(Bodies[i]);
            }
        }
        else                                            //2 or 4
        {
            if (Bodies[i]->posY < (posY + (height / 2)))    //2
            {
                q2Bodies.push_back(Bodies[i]);
            }
            else //4
            {
                q4Bodies.push_back(Bodies[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    Node* q1 = new Node(Depth + 1);
    Node* q2 = new Node(Depth + 1);
    Node* q3 = new Node(Depth + 1);
    Node* q4 = new Node(Depth + 1);

    q1->SetParam(q1Bodies, width / 2, height / 2, posX, posY);
    q2->SetParam(q2Bodies, width / 2, height / 2, posX + (width / 2), posY);
    q3->SetParam(q3Bodies, width / 2, height / 2, posX, posY + (height / 2));
    q4->SetParam(q4Bodies, width / 2, height / 2, posX + (width / 2), posY + (height / 2));

    Child.push_back(q1);
    Child.push_back(q2);
    Child.push_back(q3);
    Child.push_back(q4);

    HasChildren = true;
}

void Node::SetParam(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float pwidth, float pheight, float px, float py)
{
    Bodies = pBodies;
    posX = px;
    posY = py;
    width = pwidth;
    height = pheight;

    float mass = 0;
    double Centerx = 0;
    double Centery = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        mass += pBodies[i]->mass;
        Centerx += pBodies[i]->posX;
        Centery += pBodies[i]->posY;
    }

    TotalMass = mass;

    unsigned int size = pBodies.size();

    CenterOfMassx = Centerx / size;
    CenterOfMassy = Centery / size;

    if (Bodies.size() > 1 && Depth < _MAX_DEPTH)
    {
        GenerateChildren();
    }
}

void Node::Reset()
{
    Bodies.clear();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Child.size(); i++)
    {
        Child[i]->Reset();
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Child.size(); i++)
    {
        delete Child[i];
    }

    Child.clear();

    HasChildren = false;
}

Node::~Node()
{

}
```

And finally the main.cpp file:

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "Node.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

#define _PI 3.14159265      //Pi, used for calculations and rounded to 8 decimal places. 
#define _GRAV_CONST 0.1     //the gravitational constant. This is the timestep between each frame. Lower for slower but more accurate simulations

void BodyAttraction(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float pSoftener);                                                                       //Attracts each body to each other body in the given vector of pointers to body objects
void CalculateForceNode(Body* bi, Node* bj, float pSoftener);                                                                           //Calculate force exerted on body from node
void CalculateForce(Body* bi, Body* bj, float pSoftener);                                                                               //Calculate force exerted on eachother between two bodies
Body* CreateBody(float px, float py, float pmass, float pvx = 0, float pvy = 0);                                                        //return a pointer to new body object defined on the heap with given paramiters
void DeleteBodies(std::vector<Body*> pBodies);                                                                                          //Deletes objects pointed to by given vector
void PollEvent(sf::RenderWindow* pTarget, bool* pIsPaused, sf::View* pSimView);                                                         //Call all polled events for the sf::window
void PopulateBodyVectorDisk(std::vector<Body*> *pBodies, unsigned int pParticlesCount, float pWidth, float pHeight, float pMaxDist, float pMinDist, float pMinMass, float pMaxMass, float pGalaticCenterMass = 0);  //populate given vector with bodies with given paramiters in a disk formation
void PopulateBodyVectorUniform(std::vector<Body*> *pBodies, unsigned int pParticlesCount, float pWidth, float pHeight, float pMinMass, float pMaxMass);
void Render(sf::RenderWindow* pTarget, std::vector<Body*> pBodies, sf::Color pObjColor);                                                //Render given body objects to given screen
void SetView(sf::View* pView, sf::RenderWindow* pTarget, float pViewWidth, float pViewHeight);                                          //set the window to the simulation view
void UpdateBodies(std::vector<Body*> pBodies);                                                                                          //Calculate velocity chance from the bodies force exerted since last update, update position based on velocity, reset force to 0
void DrawNode(Node* pNode, sf::RenderWindow* pTarget);                                                                                  //Draw a node to the screen, and all of its children (recursive)
void CheckNode(Node* pNode, Body* pBody);                                                                                               //Checks if a node is sufficently far away for force calculation, if not recureses on nodes children
void OctreeBodyAttraction();                                                                                                            //Using a calculated oct-tree, calculate the force exerted on each object
void AttractToCenter(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float width, float height, float centerMass);                                                                                                                  //Attract each particle to the center of the simulation
void ResetForces(std::vector<Body*> pBodies);
void RepellFromCenter(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float width, float height, float centerMass);
                                                                                
float const DiskRadiusMax = 20000;              //Max and min distances objects will be from the galatic center
float const DiskRadiusMin = 50;
float const GalaticCenterMass = 1000000;        //The mass of the very large object simulating a black hole at the center of a galixy;
float const ObjectMassMax = 2;                  //The max and min mass of the objects in the galixy
float const ObjectMassMin = 1;
float const SimWidth = 327680;                  //Width and height of simulation, needs to be large, particles outside of this range will not be included in the octree
float const SimHeight = 327680;
float const ViewWidth = 1920;                   //Width and height of view of the simulation for the screen. 
float const ViewHeight = 1080;
float const Softener = 10;                      //A softener used for the force calculations, 10 is a good amount
unsigned int const NumParticles = 10000;        //Number of particles in simtulation, currently 2^15                                
double const _NODE_THRESHOLD = 0.5;             //Threshold for node calculations   

float zoom = 1;                                 //The current amount of zoom in or out the user has inputed in total
float MouseX = 0;
float MouseY = 0;

std::vector<Body*> Bodies;                      //Container of all Bodies in simulation
Node GlobalNode;
bool IsPaused = false;                          //Contains the state of weather the simulation is paused or not
sf::Color ObjColor(255, 255, 255, 128);         //the defult colour of the objects
sf::View SimulationView;                        
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080), "N-Body simulation");

int main()
{
    PopulateBodyVectorDisk(&Bodies, NumParticles, SimWidth, SimHeight, DiskRadiusMax, DiskRadiusMin, ObjectMassMin, ObjectMassMax, GalaticCenterMass);
    SetView(&SimulationView, &window, ViewWidth, ViewHeight);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        PollEvent(&window, &IsPaused, &SimulationView); //These will always be done

        if (!IsPaused)  //These will not if the simulation is paused
        {       
            AttractToCenter(Bodies, SimWidth, SimHeight, GalaticCenterMass);
            UpdateBodies(Bodies);
            ResetForces(Bodies);
            GlobalNode.Reset();
            GlobalNode.SetParam(Bodies, SimWidth, SimHeight);
            OctreeBodyAttraction();
        }   
        
        Render(&window, Bodies, ObjColor);
    }

    DeleteBodies(Bodies);
}

void AttractToCenter(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float width, float height, float centerMass)
{
    Body* Temp = CreateBody(width / 2, height / 2, centerMass); //Create a body at the center of the simulation

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        CalculateForce(pBodies[i], Temp, Softener);
    }

    delete Temp;
}

void RepellFromCenter(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float width, float height, float centerMass)
{
    Body* Temp = CreateBody(width / 2, height / 2, centerMass); //Create a body at the center of the simulation

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        float vectorx = Temp->posX - pBodies[i]->posX;
        float vectory = Temp->posY - pBodies[i]->posY;

        float distSqr = vectorx * vectorx + vectory * vectory;

        double Dist = (sqrt(distSqr));

        double force = (pBodies[i]->mass * Dist * _GRAV_CONST * 0.0001);

        pBodies[i]->forceX -= vectorx * force;
        pBodies[i]->forceY -= vectory * force;
    }

    delete Temp;
}

void ResetForces(std::vector<Body*> pBodies)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        pBodies[i]->forceX = 0;
        pBodies[i]->forceY = 0;
    }
}

void BodyAttraction(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float pSoftener)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < pBodies.size(); j++)
        {
            CalculateForce(pBodies.at(i), pBodies.at(j), pSoftener); //for each body in pBodies: each other body in pBodies: Calculate attractive force exerted on the first body from the second one
        }
    }
}

void OctreeBodyAttraction()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Bodies.size(); i++)
    {   
        CheckNode(&GlobalNode, Bodies[i]);
    }
}

inline void CheckNode(Node* pNode, Body* pBody)
{
    if (pNode->Bodies.size() != 0)
    {
        float diffX = (pNode->CenterOfMassx - pBody->posX);
        float diffY = (pNode->CenterOfMassy - pBody->posY);

        float distance = sqrt((diffX) * (diffX) + (diffY) * (diffY));   //Distance from the node to the object                          

        if ((pNode->width / distance) < (_NODE_THRESHOLD) || (pNode->HasChildren == false))     //if sufficently far away or has no children (external node) group node and calculate force
        {   
            CalculateForceNode(pBody, pNode, Softener);
            pNode->IsUsed = true;
        }
        else                                                                                    //if not, repeat function with children
        {
            CheckNode(pNode->Child[0], pBody);
            CheckNode(pNode->Child[1], pBody);
            CheckNode(pNode->Child[2], pBody);
            CheckNode(pNode->Child[3], pBody);
        }
    }
}

inline void CalculateForceNode(Body* bi, Node* bj, float pSoftener)  //bi is being attracted to bj. 15 flops of calculation
{
    //vector from the body to the center of mass
    float vectorx = bj->CenterOfMassx - bi->posX;
    float vectory = bj->CenterOfMassy - bi->posY;

    //c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + softener^2
    float distSqr = vectorx * vectorx + vectory * vectory + pSoftener * pSoftener;

    // ivnDistCube = 1/distSqr^(3/2)
    float distSixth = distSqr * distSqr * distSqr;
    double invDistCube = 1.0f / (sqrt(distSixth));


    double force = (bj->TotalMass * bi->mass * invDistCube * _GRAV_CONST);

    bi->forceX += vectorx * force;
    bi->forceY += vectory * force;
}

inline void CalculateForce(Body* bi, Body* bj, float pSoftener)  //bi is being attracted to bj. 15 flops of calculation
{
    //std::vector from i to j
    float vectorx = bj->posX - bi->posX;
    float vectory = bj->posY - bi->posY;

    //c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + softener^2
    float distSqr = vectorx * vectorx + vectory * vectory + pSoftener * pSoftener;

    // ivnDistCube = 1/distSqr^(3/2)
    float distSixth = distSqr * distSqr * distSqr;
    double invDistCube = 1.0f / (sqrt(distSixth));


    double force = (bj->mass * bi->mass * invDistCube * _GRAV_CONST);

    bi->forceX += vectorx * force;
    bi->forceY += vectory * force;
}

Body* CreateBody(float px, float py, float pmass, float pvx, float pvy)
{
    Body* Temp = new Body;

    Temp->posX = px;
    Temp->posY = py;
    Temp->mass = pmass;
    Temp->velX = pvx;
    Temp->velY = pvy;
    Temp->forceX = Temp->forceY = 0;

    return Temp;
}

void DeleteBodies(std::vector<Body*> pBodies)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        delete pBodies[i];
    }

    pBodies.clear();
}

void PollEvent(sf::RenderWindow* pTarget, bool* pIsPaused, sf::View* pSimView)
{
    sf::Event event;

    while (pTarget->pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            pTarget->close();
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)
                *pIsPaused = !*pIsPaused;                   //toggle what is pointed to by IsPaused
        }
        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseWheelScrolled)
        {
            zoom *= 1 + (static_cast <float> (-event.mouseWheelScroll.delta) / 10); //for each notch down, -10%, for each notch up, +10%
            pSimView->zoom(1 + (static_cast <float> (-event.mouseWheelScroll.delta) / 10));
        }
    }

    if (sf::Mouse::getPosition().x > (1920 - 20))
        SimulationView.move(2 * zoom, 0);
    if (sf::Mouse::getPosition().x < (0 + 20))
        SimulationView.move(-2 * zoom, 0);
    if (sf::Mouse::getPosition().y > (1080 - 20))
        SimulationView.move(0, 2 * zoom);
    if (sf::Mouse::getPosition().y < (0 + 20))
        SimulationView.move(0, -2 * zoom);

    pTarget->setView(*pSimView);
}

void PopulateBodyVectorDisk(std::vector<Body*> *pBodies, unsigned int pParticlesCount, float pWidth, float pHeight, float pMaxDist, float pMinDist, float pMinMass, float pMaxMass, float pGalaticCenterMass)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int> (time(0)));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pParticlesCount; i++)
    {
        float angle = static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (2 * static_cast <float> (_PI))));    //sets angle to random float range (0, 2 pi) 

        float distanceCoefficent = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        float distance = pMinDist + ((pMaxDist - pMinDist) * (distanceCoefficent * distanceCoefficent));                    //Distance point will be from the galatic center, between MinDiskRadius and MaxDiskRadius

        float positionx = cos(angle) * distance + (pWidth / 2);                                                             //set positionx and positiony to be the point you get when you go in the direction of 'angle' till you have traveled 'distance' 
        float positiony = sin(angle) * distance + (pHeight / 2);

        float orbitalVelocity = sqrt((pGalaticCenterMass * static_cast <float> (_GRAV_CONST)) / distance);                  //Calculate the orbital velocity required to orbit the galatic centre   
                                                                
        float velocityx = (sin(angle) * orbitalVelocity);
        float velocityy = (-cos(angle) * orbitalVelocity);

        float mass = pMinMass + static_cast <float> (rand() % static_cast <int> (pMaxMass - pMinMass));                     //random mass (int) in range (MinObjectMass, MaxObjectMass)

        pBodies->push_back(CreateBody(positionx, positiony, mass, velocityx, velocityy));                                   
    }
}

void PopulateBodyVectorUniform(std::vector<Body*> *pBodies, unsigned int pParticlesCount, float pWidth, float pHeight, float pMinMass, float pMaxMass)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int> (time(0)));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pParticlesCount; i++)
    {
        float positionx = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX) * pWidth + (SimWidth / 2 - pWidth / 2);                         
        float positiony = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX) * pHeight + (SimHeight / 2 - pHeight / 2);

        float mass = pMinMass + static_cast <float> (rand() % static_cast <int> (pMaxMass - pMinMass));                     //random mass (int) in range (MinObjectMass, MaxObjectMass)

        pBodies->push_back(CreateBody(positionx, positiony, mass));
    }
}

void Render(sf::RenderWindow* pTarget, std::vector<Body*> pBodies, sf::Color pObjColor)
{
    pTarget->clear();

    sf::RectangleShape Temp;
    //Temp.setFillColor(pObjColor);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {       
        if (zoom > 1)
            Temp.setSize(sf::Vector2f(pBodies.at(i)->mass * zoom, pBodies.at(i)->mass * zoom));
        else
            Temp.setSize(sf::Vector2f(pBodies.at(i)->mass, pBodies.at(i)->mass));   

        float ForceCoiffecent = sqrt(pBodies.at(i)->forceX * pBodies.at(i)->forceX + pBodies.at(i)->forceY * pBodies.at(i)->forceY) * (40000 * _GRAV_CONST);

        if (ForceCoiffecent > 1)
            ForceCoiffecent = 1;

        float Red, Green, Blue;

        Blue = 1 - (ForceCoiffecent);

        if (ForceCoiffecent < 0.2)
            Red = (ForceCoiffecent) * 5;
        else
            Red = 1;

        if (ForceCoiffecent < 0.5)
            Green = (ForceCoiffecent) * 2;
        else
            Green = 1;

        Temp.setFillColor(sf::Color(Red * 255, Green * 255, Blue * 255, 128));
        Temp.setPosition(pBodies.at(i)->posX, pBodies.at(i)->posY);
        pTarget->draw(Temp);
    }

    //DrawNode(&GlobalNode, pTarget);

    pTarget->display();
}

void DrawNode(Node* pNode, sf::RenderWindow* pTarget)
{
        sf::RectangleShape Temp;
        Temp.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        Temp.setOutlineThickness(zoom);
        Temp.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(0, 255, 0, 16));
        Temp.setPosition(pNode->posX, pNode->posY);
        Temp.setSize(sf::Vector2f(pNode->width, pNode->height));

        pTarget->draw(Temp);
    if (pNode->HasChildren) //recercivly draw all children
    {
        DrawNode(pNode->Child[0], pTarget);
        DrawNode(pNode->Child[1], pTarget);
        DrawNode(pNode->Child[2], pTarget);
        DrawNode(pNode->Child[3], pTarget);
    }
}

void SetView(sf::View* pView, sf::RenderWindow* pTarget, float pViewWidth, float pViewHeight)
{
    pView->reset(sf::FloatRect(SimWidth / 2 - pViewWidth / 2, SimHeight / 2 - pViewHeight / 2, pViewWidth, pViewHeight));
    pView->setViewport(sf::FloatRect(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f));
    pTarget->setView(*pView);
}

void UpdateBodies(std::vector<Body*> pBodies)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((pBodies[i]->posX > SimWidth && pBodies[i]->velX > 0) || (pBodies[i]->posX < 0 && pBodies[i]->velX < 0))
        {
            pBodies[i]->velX = -pBodies[i]->velX;
        }

        if ((pBodies[i]->posY > SimHeight && pBodies[i]->velY > 0) || (pBodies[i]->posY < 0 && pBodies[i]->velY < 0))
        {
            pBodies[i]->velY = -pBodies[i]->velY;
        }

        pBodies.at(i)->velX += pBodies.at(i)->forceX / pBodies.at(i)->mass;     //f = ma => force = mass * accelleration. Therefor
        pBodies.at(i)->velY += pBodies.at(i)->forceY / pBodies.at(i)->mass;     //a = f/m => accelleration = force / mass

        pBodies.at(i)->posX += pBodies.at(i)->velX;
        pBodies.at(i)->posY += pBodies.at(i)->velY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm sure there are things that can be improved, I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Thanks, I'm a little scared of a down vote backlash, Ive seen questions over on stack overflow that just dump all there code and ask for help get down voted to oblivion, But i'm guessing a question of this fashion is appropriate here?

Comment: `Please comment on anything you can see wrong with this.` - Perfect CR question, as long as everything works.  Also, you explained what it does, so you're good.

Comment: @KierenPearson Don't be scared, we don't bite! You might improve your question a bit by telling us a bit more about how it works, but either way, reviewing large amounts of code is what we do here :)

Comment: Yes I can confirm that it works like a charm, have done many time lapses with it. There is though code that is not used in here, like some functions I use for testing, and for slightly different simulations (like a uniform universe with particles scattered everywhere vs particles in a disk). Should  they be removed or kept there?

Comment: @Phrancis, What is the usual delay to getting answers on this site? Should I edit this to only contain less code?

Comment: The amount of code is not excessive. Give it a day or so, then stop by [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if you don't get an answer.

Comment: Normally in my reviews I always say never use pointers (its usually a bad idea). But this time I have a question first :-) In `std::vector<Body*> Bodies;` is there a particular reason why you are storing a vector of pointers rather than a vector of Body?

Comment: I was thinking to myself, well its because i want to make the object lightweight as possible, because it gets passed around alot. This is why the vector of children each node has is just pointers to objects on the heap, because if they are just `Node` objects then if you see it makes generating children very slow. I believe now this is not a correct solution, so if I did have a `std::vector<Body> Bodies` how would I pass it to a function quickly? Would it be `void SomeFunction(std::vector<Body> &Bodies)`? @Loki Astari

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code was big so my review of it will probably not be that complete.  I'll try to go in order of top to bottom of the code that was listed.

### Force vs Acceleration

In your `body` structure, you track `forceX` and `forceY`.  It would be better to track `accelerationX` and `accelerationY`, because you will save yourself some computation.  When you compute the force acting on a body due to gravity, the formula is this:

> ```
> double force = (bj->mass * bi->mass * invDistCube * _GRAV_CONST);
> ```

And then when you update the position, you do this:

> ```
> pBodies.at(i)->velX += pBodies.at(i)->forceX / pBodies.at(i)->mass;
> ```

If you notice, you multiplied the mass of the body into the force and then divided it out later on.  If you computed the acceleration, you would skip those two steps.

```
 double accel = (bj->mass * invDistCube * _GRAV_CONST);
 ...
 pBodies.at(i)->velX += pBodies.at(i)->accelX;
```

I did notice that you used the force to determine the color.  To maintain that behavior, you could either multiply the acceleration by the mass to recompute the force (still saving a division).  Or you could switch to coloring by acceleration, which may be interesting to see.

### Building the quadtree

**Bounding box**

When you build the quadtree, one thing you could do is to compute the actual bounding box for each `Node` instead of using the bounding box that was passed in.  Right now for example, the top level nodes of the quadtree are the four quadrants of your screen.  But if the bodies within a quadrant only occupy a small part of that quadrant, you are still using the full size of the quadrant.

Computing the bounding box is easy, since you already iterate through all the bodies when you create a node.  By using the actual bounding box, you could get a more accurate measurement of the "threshold" that you use to determine if a quadrant is far enough away from a body to be considered a single body.

Of course if you do this, you shouldn't just use `width` to be the quandrant size as you are doing now.  You would need to compute something like the diagonal width of the quadrant to be your quadrant size.

**Dividing point of child quadrants**

Currently you generate your child quadrants by using the center of the parent quadrant as the dividing point.  If you compute the actual bounding box as mentioned above, and then use the center of the bounding box as the dividing point, it will probably divide your bodies a bit better than before.

But another idea would be to use the center of mass of the quadrant as your dividing point.  I'm not entirely sure this would work better than the geometric center, but you could try it and find out.

### Node::SetParam()

You have this variable:

> ```
> unsigned int size = pBodies.size();
> ```

But you still use `pBodies.size()` two other places in the function.  Also this line of code:

> ```
> CenterOfMassx = Centerx / size;
> ```

looks bad to me because `size` is often zero.  Although you *can* divide by zero with doubles, I would suggest checking for `size == 0` near the top and avoiding most of the code entirely.

### Node::Reset()

You can shorten this code:

> ```
> for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Child.size(); i++)
> {
>     Child[i]->Reset();
> }
>
> for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Child.size(); i++)
> {
>     delete Child[i];
> }
> ```

to this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Child.size(); i++)
{
    Child[i]->Reset();
    delete Child[i];
}
```

### AttractToCenter(), RepellFromCenter()

First of all, `RepellFromCenter()` is never used, so it can be removed.  As for `AttractToCenter()`, I would just create an extra body with the galactic mass and let your code handle it like any other body.  You just have to make sure that after each iteration, you reposition the galactic mass back to the galactic center if you don't want it to move.

### pSoftener

1. I don't like the name, because it makes me think that it is a pointer but it actually isn't.
2. It can only ever take on the value of the global constant `Softener`.  So you could remove it as a parameter and then just use the global constant instead.

### CheckNode()

Here, you check if a body is far enough away from a node to be able to consider the node as a single center of mass.  The check looks like this:

> ```
> float distance = sqrt((diffX) * (diffX) + (diffY) * (diffY));                       
>
> if ((pNode->width / distance) < (_NODE_THRESHOLD) || (pNode->HasChildren == false))
> ```

I don't really like the parentheses in the `if` statement, since all of them are redundant.  It could look like this:

```
if (pNode->width / distance < _NODE_THRESHOLD || !pNode->HasChildren)
```

Beyond that, I think you could save yourself a call to `sqrt()` by using the distance squared instead of the distance.  So in other words, instead of:

```
if (nodeWidth / distance < _NODE_THRESHOLD)
```

you could do:

```
if (nodeWidthSquared / distanceSquared < _NODE_THRESHOLD_SQUARED)
```

### CalculateForceNode() vs. CalculateForce()

These are very nearly the same function.  I would suggest that each `Node` should contain a `Body` which holds the center of mass information for that node.  That way, you could eliminate `CalculateForceNode()` and just pass in `node->centerOfMassBody` to `CalculateForce()` instead.  If you did that, you could also eliminate `node->TotalMass`, `node->CenterOfMassx`, and `node->CenterOfMassy` since all that information would be in `node->centerOfMassBody` already.

### Miscellaneous

I only skimmed the rest of the code.  So here are some other small things:

1. Misspellings such as `Coiffecent` vs `Coefficient`, `Repell` vs `Repel`.
2. Extra parentheses in expressions (which possibly aren't that bad, it's a style thing).
3. You defined your own pi constant, but you could just use `M_PI`.

### In response to comments

1. As far as non-square nodes are concerned, I don't see any reason why rectangular nodes can't be used as long as you use the diagonal as the "width" for determining thresholds.  But I'm not familiar with the Barnes Hut algorithm so there may be some theoretical reason why square nodes are better.
2. For particles ejected from the Galaxy, I suppose the bounding boxes would increase in size, but I doubt that would matter much.  You could always exclude outliers, as you said.
3. I believe that `SetParams()` can be called with size zero vectors.  Imagine if `GenerateChildren()` were called with 2 bodies.  It creates 4 new nodes, two of which are empty and two of which have 1 body.  All four of these nodes have `SetParams()` called on them, so two of these will have size zero vectors.
4. I know that `a/b` is not the same as `a^2/b^2`, but I was comparing to the threshold squared also.  For positive `a` and `b`, this relation holds: if `a/b < 0.5`, then `a^2/b^2 < 0.25`.
5. I thought that `M_PI` was defined in `math.h`, but apparently that is not universally true.  I'm used to Gnu, where `M_PI` is defined.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you put into this. Your idea to use acceleration not force is very good, I don't know how you saw that. For the bounding box section, I cant split it by center of mass, because each node must be square, and such it must be split down the center. For your idea about the bounding box, are you saying the top level node (The one that is the entire simulation) should insted be the smallest it can be to include all the particles? One issue with that is particles can be ejected from the galixy, and then the bounding box could be larger than it started! Cont.

Comment: I could impliment a maximum size of the global box, but that size would be reached quickly, I could exclude the top 5% and the botton 5% of particle position values (Remove the outliers) but that causes when the simulation starts the particles on the outscirts of the galixy to not be attracted at all.

Comment: "looks bad to me because size is often zero. Although you can divide by zero with doubles, I would suggest checking for size == 0 near the top and avoiding most of the code entirely." Yes this is somthing that delicitly does not occur but I will include more saftey as of now. SetParam does not get called anywhere other than GenerateChildren(), which only gets called from SetParam() if the size of its body vector is greater than one. A delicate situation indeed ;P

Comment: `if (nodeWidthSquared / distanceSquared < _NODE_THRESHOLD_SQUARED)` does not work, because the ratio `a/b` is not equal to the ratio `a^2/b^2` and the only way to use `a^2/b^2` is to afterwards `sqrt(a^2/b^2)` which just returns `a/b` and your back to where you started, but you needed a extra multiplication to square the `pNode->width`

Comment: Yes im bad at spelling XD thanks. I tried to use M_PI but its `not defined`, do I need to include a specific header?

Comment: 1) The truth is I don't know. 2) They just travel further and further away from the galixy, never disapearing, but once they go outside of the simulation width then they do not attract objects to themselves. 3) Your right, my bad 4)Your right my bad XD 5) Ha! I was right about something. Thanks again for your feedback. Should I post the new updated code as a edit or not?

Comment: @KierenPearson No, don't post updated code as an edit.  What you can do is make a new question after you have made all your fixups, and ask for a rereview (if you want one).  If you don't want a rereview, you can maybe add a short addendum to your question describing what you fixed up, or do it in comments.

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting piece of code, and a well written question, so I'm sure you'll get a number of good reviews.  Here are some observations that may help you improve your code.

### Refine your objects

The `Node` and `Body` objects both have exclusively public members, which is not very good design.  Every piece of code that interacts with them then reaches inside and manipulates the object members directly which is prone to error and makes maintenance difficult.  So as a simple example, let's consider `Body`.  First, you could make it into a `class` rather than a `struct`.  Next, some of the functions within `main` really should instead be member functions of `Body`. To take a few obvious examples, the `CalculateForce` and `CalculateForceNode` should instead be member functions:

```
// updates force based on other body
void CalculateForce(const Body* bj, float pSoftener);  
// updates force based on other node
void CalculateForce(const Node* bj, float pSoftener);
```

Note also that the other `Body` or `Node` is not adjusted, so it is declared as `const`.

It would also be a good idea to encapsulate `Bodies` in `main.cpp` as an object with member functions rather than passing it around to stand-alone functions.

### Use constructors

The `CreateBody` function in `main` should instead be a constructor for `Body`:

```
Body(float px, float py, float pmass, float pvx=0, float pvy=0) :
    posX(px), 
    posY(py),
    velX(pvx),
    velY(pvy),
    forceX(0),
    forceY(0),
    mass(pmass)
{}
```

This also allows the temporary `Body` created in `AttractToCenter` (and the unused `RepellFromCenter`) to be created on the stack instead of the heap, avoiding both `new` and `delete` in that function.

### Use references to pass complex objects

Most of the functions in `main` which take a `std::vector<Body*>` as the first argument should instead be declared to take a reference instead.  So for example,

```
void AttractToCenter(std::vector<Body*> pBodies, float width, float height, float centerMass)
```

becomes

```
void AttractToCenter(std::vector<Body*> &pBodies, float width, float height, float centerMass)
```

The difference is just the single `&` character in front of `pBodies` but the performance impact is large because it prevents the compiler from having to actually make a copy of the vector.

With all of the above suggestion and this one implemented, that function becomes quite small and simple:

```
void AttractToCenter(std::vector<Body*> &pBodies, float width, float height, float centerMass)
{
    Body Temp(width / 2, height / 2, centerMass); //Create a body at the center of the simulation
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        pBodies[i]->CalculateForce(&Temp, Softener);
    }
}
```

It could be even simpler, if your compiler isn't too old, as shown in the next suggestion.

### Use "range-for" to simplify your code

If your compiler fully supports the C++11 standard, you can use a "range-for" to simplify your code.  The loop above, for example, can be written like this:

```
for (auto &pB : pBodies)
{
    pB->CalculateForce(&Temp, Softener);
}
```

### Avoid the use of global variables

Most of the global variables that are not constants should probably be restricted to a smaller scope.  For instance, `IsPaused` can simply be moved into `main` -- it does not have to be a global variable.  Doing so will reduce the hidden linkages between functions and help you strengthen your interface and design and reduce the difficulty of maintenance.

### Use forward slashes in include paths

Using this path for your include file only works under Windows:

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
```

If you use a forward slash instead, it works on all platforms.

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
```

### Prefer `const` values to `#define`s

Both `_GRAV_CONST` and `_PI` should be declared as `const float` values rather than as `#define`s.  Doing so allows for better type safety and in this particular case, allows for the elimination of a messy `static_cast`.

### Consider using a better random number generator

If you are using a compiler that supports at least C++11, consider using a better random number generator.  In particular, instead of `rand`, you might want to look at [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) and friends in the `<random>` header.

### Eliminate memory leaks

There are a number of places where `new` is called without any corresponding `delete` calls.  This is the recipe for a memory leak.  Either fix the leak by adding specific calls to `delete`, or even better, use smart pointers to eliminate `new` and `delete` entirely.  One basic thing that would help a great deal is to decide which objects actually own the `Body` and `Node` items.  That will help you to decide if and when they should be deleted.